# Sum cells if entries exist: Else without If

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I want to sum everything from G5 down, but if G6 is blank (i.e. there is only one entry), then just sum G5.

I get an error

> Else without If

If I put `If` after the `Else`, I get another syntax error.

```vb
Sub TotalR()

Sheets("Data").Select

Dim Rng As Range
Dim c As Range

If IsEmpty(Range("g6")) = True Then Range("g6").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=sum(g5)"
Else:
    Set Rng = Range("g5:g" & Range("g5").End(xlDown).Row)
    Set c = Range("g5").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
    c.Formula = "=SUM(" & Rng.Address(False, False) & ")"

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `If IsEmpty(Range("g6")) = True Then Range("g6").Select` needs to be split into two lines after the `Then`

Answer (score 0):

Move Range("g6").Select down to the next line (otherwise that line is a complete If statement). Also, remove the colon from the Else line.

```
Sub TotalR()
   Dim Rng As Range
   Dim c As Range

   Sheets("Data").Select
   If IsEmpty(Range("g6")) = True Then
        Range("g6").Select
        ActiveCell.Formula = "=sum(g5)"
    Else
        Set Rng = Range("g5:g" & Range("g5").End(xlDown).Row)
        Set c = Range("g5").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
        c.Formula = "=SUM(" & Rng.Address(False, False) & ")"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused exactly like @Scott Craner mentioned, you need to split to 2 lines:

```
If IsEmpty(Range("g6")) = True Then 
    Range("g6").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=sum(g5)"
```

However, it's better if you stay away from  `Select` and `ActiveCell` , and instead use referenced objects as `Worksheets` and `Range`s.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub TotalR()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim c As Range

With Sheets("Data")    
    If IsEmpty(.Range("G6")) Then
        .Range("G6").Formula = "=Sum(G5)"
    Else
        Set Rng = .Range("G5:G" & .Range("G5").End(xlDown).Row)
        Set c = .Range("G5").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
        c.Formula = "=SUM(" & Rng.Address(False, False) & ")"
    End If    
End With

End Sub
```